# Azure Static Web App not respecting staticwebapp.config.json

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-static-web-app

I am testing a simple html page with Azure Static Web Apps (SWA) and want to implement an IP restriction so I can only view the site. I also have a simple Azure Devops task to push the project.

The issue is while the pipeline output shows the task finding and reading the swa.config.json file the site is still accessible from other IPs other than my own. Even if I set `allowedIpRanges` to an empty list `[""]` the site is still accessible even though that should not allow any IPs to access the site.

My project structure:

```
project_folder/
|    - index.html
|    _ staticwebapp.config.json
```

My staticwebapp.config.json:

```
{
  "networking": {
    "allowedIpRanges": ["MY_IP"]
  }
}
```

Azure Devops Task:

```
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/project_folder/
    app_location: /
    output_location: ''
    is_static_export: true
    skip_app_build: true
    skip_api_build: true
    verbose: true
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(SWA_DEPLOYMENT_TOKEN)
```

The pipeline output:

```
Verbose logging enabled
Build timeout not specified, defaulting to 15 minutes
App Directory Location: '/' was found.
Looking for event info
Event info parsed from action options.
Skipping step to build /working_dir with Oryx
Found staticwebapp.config.json file: 'staticwebapp.config.json'
Didn't find Oryx manifest file under location: /a2b4be88-c84d-41ed-acfe-2f2c9b2f87b1-swa-oryx/app-manifest/oryx-manifest.toml
Determined default file to be: index.html
Using 'staticwebapp.config.json' file for configuration information, 'routes.json' will be ignored.
No Api directory specified. Azure Functions will not be created.
Either no Api directory was specified, or the specified directory was not found. Azure Functions will not be created.
Zipping App Artifacts
App Zip will be created from directory: /working_dir
Done Zipping App Artifacts
Uploading build artifacts.
Skipping function upload as functions are identical to last successful deployment.
Finished Upload. Polling on deployment.
Status: InProgress. Time: 0.057026(s)
Status: Succeeded. Time: 15.225704(s)
Deployment Complete :)
Visit your site at: https://asdf.azurestaticapps.net
Thanks for using Azure Static Web Apps!
Exiting
Finishing: AzureStaticWebApp
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have tried to repro the same using the below steps and got the results as expected.**

**Step 1:** Initialize repo and add **index.html** and **staticwebapp.config.json** files.

**staticwebapp.config.json:**

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/*",
      "serve": "/index.html",
      "statusCode": 200
    }
  ],
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html",
    "statusCode": 200
  },
  "networking": {
    "allowedIpRanges": [
      "49.204.176.183/32"
    ]
  }
}
```

In the above configuration file, **49.204.176.183** under networking is my public IP address. If you are allowing a single IP, use `/32` CIDR block.

Please refer networking section [in this ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration) for more information.

**Step 2:** Create and run the pipeline and verify the webapp whether it is accessible or not.
Below is the azure static webapp task in pipeline.

```
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: 
    app_location: '/'
    skip_app_build: true
    skip_api_build: true
    is_static_export: true
    verbose: true
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: '$(SWA_DEPLOYMENT_TOKEN)'
```

[image]

**Step 3:** Now change IP address to any other address and run pipeline to verify the network configuration applied.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a free or paid static web app? It wasn't clear from the Microsoft documentation if IP restrictions are only supported for the paid SKU or available to all. Regardless, I decided to use AAD authentication instead (posted in standalone answer)

Comment: For future reference, you need the standard plan in order to allow ip addresses, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/quotas).

Answer (score 0):

While I couldn't figure out the IP restrictions on the free SKU of Azure Static Web Apps, I used AAD auth instead with the **paid** sku and the following configuration in my staticwebapp.config.json file.

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/*",
      "allowedRoles": ["authenticated"]
    }
  ],
  "auth": {
    "identityProviders": {
      "azureActiveDirectory": {
        "userDetailsClaim": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
        "registration": {
          "openIdIssuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<subId>",
          "clientIdSettingName": "AZURE_CLIENT_ID",
          "clientSecretSettingName": "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "responseOverrides": {
    "401": {
      "statusCode": 302,
      "redirect": "/.auth/login/aad"
    }
  },
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html",
    "exclude": ["/images/*.{png,jpg,gif}", "/css/*"]
  },
  "globalHeaders": {
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
  }
}
```